# Return true if current item is in provided range

Tags: java

Just having a few problems with this:

> Return true if the current item is in the range provided i.e., between rows row1 and row 2 (inclusive) and between columns column1 and column2 (inclusive), false otherwise.

I've put the console at the bottom. Thanks.

```
public boolean inRange(int row1, int column1, int row2, int column2) {

    System.out.println(row1 + " " + column1 + " " + row2 + " " + column2);

    if(this.row >= row1 && this.row <= row2 && this.column >= column1 && this.column <= column2)
    { 
        System.out.println("True" + "\n");
        return true;
    }
    else if(this.row <= row1 && this.row >= row2 && this.column <= column1 && this.column >= column2)
    { 
        System.out.println("True" + "\n");
        return true;
    }

    System.out.println("False" + "\n");
    return false;
}
```

Console output:

```
2 4 0 0
True
3 5 2 4
True
5 4 2 5
False
```

Comment: [Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the **desired behavior**, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What exactly is your problem now? There are only two possible outcomes of your method, either the item is within the defined ranges or not. Hence the boolean return value. You test for three different cases, however.

Comment: Probably one of your classmates :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/47010602/823393

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're obviously trying to handle row or column ranges given in either *ascending* order (e.g., `row1 <= row2`) or *descending* order (e.g., `column2 <= column1`).

Here's the problem:  your first test:

```
if(this.row >= row1 && this.row <= row2 && 
   this.column >= column1 && this.column <= column2)
    ...
```

correctly detects if `this.row` is within an *ascending* row range and `this.column` is within an *ascending* column range.

Your second test:

```
if(this.row <= row1 && this.row >= row2 && 
   this.column <= column1 && this.column >= column2)
        ...
```

correctly detects when `this.row` is within a *descending* row range and `this.column` is within a *descending* column range.

But what if the given row range is in *ascending* order while the given column range is in *descending* order?  Or if, as in your third test case, the row range is *descending* and the column range is *ascending*?

You need a test that can handle any combination of range orderings:

```
if((this.row >= row1 && this.row <= row2 ||
    this.row <= row1 && this.row >= row2)
         && 
    (this.column >= column1 && this.column <= column2 || 
     this.column <= column1 && this.column >= column2))
{ 
    System.out.println("True" + "\n");
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My thought is As per your question else if condition not needed.

In else if you are checking row and column are out of range. just remove it

Answer (score 0):

> Return true if the current item is in the range provided i.e., between rows row1 and row 2 (inclusive) and between columns column1 and column2 (inclusive), false otherwis

The tasks asks you to check for two states: either it is in range or it is not. But you are checking for three states. If I understood your problem correctly, then this should be the working code:

```
public boolean inRange(int row1, int column1, int row2, int column2) {
    return this.row >= row1 && this.row <= row2 && this.column >= column1 && this.column <= column2;
}
```

Comment: with out bothering to know if the functionality works, if check isn't required at all :P

Comment: @yekac what value is `this.row` and `this.column` in your example?

Comment: @yekac If we take your example row = 2, column = 4, row1 = 5, column1 = 0, row2 = 5 and column2 = 0. then the correct result should always be false. short explanation: row(with value 2) is not bigger or equal to row1(with value 5). java wont run the rest of the statement and simply return false. maybe post your entire code in a git gist, so I can look at it?

Comment: @yekac I looked through your code and everything seems to be working as it should be. only the tests are wrong, as already explained `assertTrue(entry.inRange(5, 5, 0, 0));`should be false if row = 2 and column = 4. did you create these testcases yourself? if not ask your teacher/mentor if he did a mistake